Propositional Logic negation
In propositional logic, it is commonly said that If A then B (A -> B) is the same as IF Not A then Not B (¬ A -> ¬ B).
For example: in the case (A -> B)
If Z equals 2 then W equals 4.
Where, A (Z = 2) and B (W = 4)
In this case Z = 2 implies that W = 4, and when Z ≠ 2 does not imply that W is equal to any number.
In the case of Contraposition.: (¬B -> ¬A)
If  W is not equal to 4 then Z is not equal to 2
In this case, W ≠ 4 implies that Z ≠ 2, and when W=4 does not imply that Z is different from any number.
Is it not saying different things ?

You are talking about contraposition, aren't you ? $(A \implies B) \iff (\neg B \implies \neg A)$


In propositional logic, it is commonly said that If A then B (A -> B) is the same as IF Not A then Not B (¬ A -> ¬ B).

No, this is not said. That's is not a valid equality, as your figured out yourself.
What we do have is so-called contraposition:

$A \to B \Longleftrightarrow \neg B \to \neg A$

Using your example, "If $z = 2$ then $w = 4$" is equivalent to "If $w \neq 4$ then $z \neq 2$".
